# ArcGIS API for Silverlight & Microsoft Active Directory Security

Tags: arcgis-server, security, arcgis-silverlight-viewer

I am trying to get a Silverlight app working with an Esri map service, secured with Active Directory authentication.

I found an example online of how to get the app working when using User Store authentication at https://developers.arcgis.com/silverlight/sample-code/start.htm#IdentityManagerServices.

Does anyone know how I can get the app working correctly when the user has a map service with Active Directory authentication?

Answer (score 1):

The AD integration could be happening in a couple of different ways:

1) at the web tier, i.e. using ArcGIS Web Adaptor in IIS, in which case the authentication will happen through the browser transparently to the application, and you shouldn't have to do anything explicitly at the app level

2) at the server tier, in which case it will be exposed to the application using classic ArcGIS Server token-based security; this is no different from an app point of view to using the built-in user store

Can you share more details on what problems you're running into?